# Rolling Regression on time series; Smooth change of coefficients

Tags: r

I can do a rolling regression

```
library(zoo)

seat <- as.zoo(log(UKDriverDeaths))
time(seat) <- as.yearmon(time(seat))
seat <- merge(y = seat, y1 = lag(seat, k = -1),
y12 = lag(seat, k = -12), all = FALSE)

tail(seat)
fm <- rollapply(seat, width = 50,
FUN = function(z) coef(lm(y ~ y1 + y12, data = as.data.frame(z))),
by.column = FALSE, align = "right")

fm
```

Looking at the intercept plot, this varies a great deal.

```
plot(fm[,1]
```

I would like to have the best smoothed coefficients which do not wildly vary through time but vary smoothly. Is there a way to do this (considering only past data at any point).

The package walker (Bayesian Regression with Time-Varying Coefficients) does this, but it calculates the coefficients using all the data and not considering only past data at any point.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that we can shorten the code to this using the dyn package:

```
library(dyn)

seat <- as.zoo(log(UKDriverDeaths))
coef_fun <- function(z) coef(dyn$lm(z ~ lag(z, c(-1, -12)), z))
zcoef <- rollapplyr(seat, 50, coef_fun, coredata = FALSE)
```

We could simply smooth the coefficients with `rollmean` (or `rollmeanr` if we don't want dependence on the future):

```
zsmooth <- rollmeanr(zcoef, 3)
plot(zsmooth)
```

Use a larger width if that is not smooth enough.